# Make 'less' behave like 'tail -f'

Tags: bash

`tail -f` does what it's meant to do pretty well, but it's rather limited when some more control is needed, i.e. when stopping/resuming text would be useful.

Would it be possible to use `less` instead of `tail -f`?

Answer (score 2):

```
less -W +F somelogfile
```

Using `-W` highlights the first (unread) new line after any forward movement such as scrolling to the next page.

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (on windows) will put you back into normal mode
<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> will resume the 'tailling' (as mentioned above)
<kbd>g</kbd> will take you to the beginning of the file
<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> will take you to the end of the file
<kbd>f</kbd> will forward you one page
<kbd>b</kbd> will take you back one page
<kbd>q</kbd> will quit the program

Answer courtesy of **[wilmoore](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1024/make-less-behave-like-tail-f.#comments)**